# Variance where the distribution depends on another distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be the result of one roll of a $6$-sided unbiased die, and let $Y$ be the result of one roll of an $X$-sided die. How would I go about calculating the mean, variance and distribution of $Y$?

Comment: Do you know that $E[Y] = \sum_{x=1}^6 E[Y \mid X=x] P(X=x)$? The [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) and [total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and conditioned on $X=i$, $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,\ldots,i\}$. We may then compute

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y=k) &= \bigcup_{i=1}^k \mathbb P\left(\left\{Y=k \right\}\cap \left\{X=i\right\}\right)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \mathbb P\left(\left\{Y=k \right\}\cap \left\{X=i\right\}\right)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \mathbb P(Y=k\mid X=i)\mathbb P(X=i)\\
&= \frac16\sum_{i=1}^k \frac1i\cdot \mathsf 1_{\{1,2,\ldots,i\}}(k)\\
&= \frac16\sum_{i=k}^6 \frac1i.
\end{align}

This yields
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y=1) &= \frac16 \sum_{i=1}^6 \frac 1i = \frac{49}{120}\\
\mathbb P(Y=2) &= \frac16 \sum_{i=2}^6 \frac 1i = \frac{29}{120}\\
\mathbb P(Y=3) &= \frac16 \sum_{i=3}^6 \frac 1i = \frac{19}{120}\\
\mathbb P(Y=4) &= \frac16 \sum_{i=4}^6 \frac 1i = \frac{37}{360}\\
\mathbb P(Y=5) &= \frac16 \sum_{i=5}^6 \frac 1i = \frac{11}{180}\\
\mathbb P(Y=6) &= \frac16 \sum_{i=6}^6 \frac 1i = \frac1{36}.\\
\end{align}
It follows that 
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y] &= \sum_{k=1}^6 k\cdot\mathbb P(Y=k)\\
&= \frac{49}{120} + 2\cdot\frac{29}{120} + 3\cdot \frac{19}{120} + 4\cdot \frac{37}{360}+5\cdot\frac{11}{180}+6\cdot\frac1{36}\\
&= \frac94
\end{align} and
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y^2] &= \sum_{k=1}^6 k\cdot\mathbb P(Y=k)\\
&= \frac{49}{120} + 2^2\cdot\frac{29}{120} + 3^2\cdot \frac{19}{120} + 4^2\cdot \frac{37}{360}+5^2\cdot\frac{11}{180}+6^2\cdot\frac1{36}\\
&= \frac{251}{36},
\end{align}
and hence
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(Y) &= \mathbb E\left[Y^2\right] - \mathbb E[Y]^2\\
&= \frac{251}{36} - \left(\frac94\right)^2\\
&= \frac{85}{18}.
\end{align}